# Number Sequence generation using NumberSeq Class

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I created a number sequence in the form using numberSeq class newgetNum Method.

It is creating number sequence perfectly.

But the problem raised after deleting the record without saving the record.

After that creating a new record generates new number rather than the deleted number.

Eg :1. CTRL+N => record "001" is created

```
2. Delete "001" without saving

3. CTRL+N => record "002" is created

But we want to generate 001 only.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to set the "continues" flag on the number sequence to reuse deleted numbers.

Also your form should use the `NumberSeqFormHandler` class, see  the [Number Sequence Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa608474%28v=ax.50%29.aspx) documentation.